# dialogflow error for microsoft transaltor

Tags: javascript, http-post, dialogflow-es, dialogflow-es-fulfillment

I am trying to call the below function is dialogflow but I am unable to response body

```
function calltransliterate(agent) {
        console.log('calltransliterate');
         return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
         const trnstext= agent.parameters.trnsvar;
         var trnsaltedtext =null;
         var key_var = '**API_KEY**';
         var subscriptionKey = key_var;
         var endpoint_var = 'https://api.cognitive.microsofttranslator.com/';
         var endpoint = endpoint_var;

         let options = {
        method: 'POST',
        baseUrl: endpoint,
        url: 'transliterate',
        qs: {
          'api-version': '3.0',
         'language': 'ja',
      'fromScript': 'jpan',
      'toScript': 'latn'
        },
        headers: {
          'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key': subscriptionKey,
          'Content-type': 'application/json',
          'X-ClientTraceId': uuidv4().toString()
        },
        body: [{
              'text': trnstext
        }],
        json: true,
        };

           console.log('before request');
           requestModule.get(options, (error, response, body) =>{
           console.log('after request');           
           console.log(  (body)); //error occures here 
      });

   });
}
```

but    console.log(  (body)); message: 'The request method is not supported for the requested resource.'

Answer (score 1):

Although you are setting `options.method` to "POST", you're then calling `requestModule.get()`, which would change the method to "GET".

Try something more like

```
requestModule.post( options, (error, response, body) => {
  //...
});
```